# Compiler ignore threads priorities

Tags: java, multithreading

I tried to compile the example from Thinking in Java by Bruce Eckel:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class SimplePriorities implements Runnable {
  private int countDown = 5;
  private volatile double d; // No optimization
  private int priority;
  public SimplePriorities(int priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
  }
  public String toString() {
    return Thread.currentThread() + ": " + countDown;
  }
  public void run() {
    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(priority);
    while(true) {
      // An expensive, interruptable operation:
      for(int i = 1; i < 100000; i++) {
        d += (Math.PI + Math.E) / (double)i;
        if(i % 1000 == 0)
          Thread.yield();
      }
      System.out.println(this);
      if(--countDown == 0) return;
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      exec.execute(
        new SimplePriorities(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY));
    exec.execute(
        new SimplePriorities(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY));
    exec.shutdown();
  }
}
```

According to the book, the output has to look like:

```
Thread[pool-1-thread-6,10,main]: 5
Thread[pool-1-thread-6,10,main]: 4
Thread[pool-1-thread-6,10,main]: 3
Thread[pool-1-thread-6,10,main]: 2
Thread[pool-1-thread-6,10,main]: 1
Thread[pool-1-thread-3,1,main]: 5
Thread[pool-1-thread-2,1,main]: 5
Thread[pool-1-thread-1,1,main]: 5
...
```

But in my case 6th thread doesn't execute its task at first and threads are disordered. Could you please explain me what's wrong? I just copied the source and didn't add any strings of code.

Comment: Independent if the thread priorities are working or not - your question title indicates a misconception. The compiler compiled what you told it to compile. This has nothing to do with the compiler. This is only rooted in the way threads are implemented at runtime.

Comment: The order of the output is undefined, and if the book says any different it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine and with the output from the book.

Your IDE probably has console window with the scroll bar - just scroll it up and see the 6th thread first doing its job.

However, the results may differ depending on OS / JVM version. This code runs as expected for me on Windows 10 / JVM 8

Comment: Sure? The last time I spent hours to write code that would use thread priorities... Neither Linux nor various versions of windows did care about them. If you get this example to work I am really interested what JVM and OS you are using.

Comment: I've just ran it on my Windows 10 PC using JVM 8

Comment: Funny. I guess I have to look into my experiment code then. But you should enhance your answer and point out that this may depend on OS and JVM type / version.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

**If two threads with the same priority want to write output, which one goes first?**

The order of threads (with the same priority) is undefined, therefore the order of output is undefined. It is likely that a single thread is allowed to write several outputs in a row (because that's how most thread schedulers work), but it could also be completely random, or anything in between.

**How many threads will a cached thread pool create?**

That depends on your system. If you run on a dual-core system, creating more than 4 threads is pointless, because there hardly won't be any CPU available to execute those threads. In this scenario further tasks will be queued and executed only after earlier tasks are completed.

Hint: there is also a fixed-size thread pool, experimenting with that should change the output.

In summary there is nothing wrong with your code, it is just wrong to assume that threads are executed in any order. It is even technically possible (although very unlikely), that the first task is already completed before the last task is even started. If your book says that the above order is "correct" then the book is simply wrong. On an average system that might be the most likely output, but - as above - with threads there is never any order, unless you enforce it.

One way to enforce it are thread priorities - higher priorities will get their work done first - you can find other concepts in the [concurrent package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).